# Automate Control-M to run job using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, control-m

I need to automate Control-M to run jobs using Selenium Java. I am thinking if I could do it via Rest API calls. Is there any other way? If API calls, where can I find the documentation?

I tried using xpath, I couldn't locate the jobs using web elements, since it is canvas element and way more complicated. So thought API calls would be best. Any thoughts would help!!

Comment: Checkout this https://documents.bmc.com/supportu/API/Helix/en-US/Documentation/API_Tutorials_Main.htm